# SVG: Circle with sector with textPath

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I'm absolutly beginner with SVG, and I have to create something like this picture:

[image]

Spec:

- Circle
- With a top sector (90°)
- With some text at the top sector

This is my Try:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" style="fill:none;stroke:#00be00;stroke-width:5" />
    <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:#be3000" d="M 15,37 A 50,50 0 0 1 80,50" />

    <text text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-size: 6px;">Hello World</textPath>
    </text>

</svg>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hprLxat/2/

I don't know:

- How Align the top sector with the circle.
- How to Make the textPath transparent.
- Why the circle is overflow the viewBox
  Thenks you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe so

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -10 120 120">

          <!-- Green circle    -->
   <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="50" style="fill:none;stroke:#92D050;stroke-width:10" />
    <!-- Red segment -->
     <circle  cx="55" cy="55" r="50" stroke="#C0504D" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="78.5 235.5" stroke-dashoffset="117.75" fill="none" />
          <!-- Path for text -->
  <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:none" d="M 9,50 A 46,46.5 0 0 1 100.5,50" /> 
 <text text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight:700;">Hello World</textPath>
    </text>

</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

---

*Calculation of the length of the red sector*

Full circle length at `R ="50"` on which the sector is located

`C=2 * PI * R = 314`

A quarter of the length of the full circle that the red sector occupies is `314/4 = 78.5`

The formula `stroke-dasharray ="78.5 235.5"` where 78.5 is a dash; 235.5 - gap

---

> How Align the top sector with the circle.

Top sector alignment is implemented using the attribute `stroke-dashoffset="117.75"`

This attribute indicates the offsets of the beginning of the circle. We move the circle a quarter of a turn and another eighth  `78.5 + 39.25 = 117.75`

> How to Make the textPath transparent.

`style="fill:none;stroke:none"`

> Why the circle is overflow the viewBox

Since the wide line is located symmetrically with respect to the contour of the circle, its outer part is cut off.

[image]

I had to expand the `viewBox` and move the whole image down by 10px  `viewBox="0 -10 120 120"`

### Bonus

An example of animating text movement within a sector

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -10 120 120">

          <!-- Green circle    -->
   <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="50" style="fill:none;stroke:#92D050;stroke-width:10" />
    <!-- Red segment -->
     <circle  cx="55" cy="55" r="50" stroke="#C0504D" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="78.5 235.5" stroke-dashoffset="117.75" fill="none" />
          <!-- Path for text -->
  <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:none" d="M 9,50 A 46,46.5 0 0 1 100.5,50" /> 
 <text id="txt1" text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight:700;">Hello World 
      <!-- Text movement animation starts after a click -->
       <animate
      begin="svg1.click"
   dur="4s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="50%;42%;50%;50%;58%;50%;50%"/>
   </textPath> 
         <!-- Text repainting animation starts after a click    -->
    <animate
      attributeName="fill"
   to="yellow"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="0.2s"
   fill="freeze" /> 
     </text> 
 
 <text x="46%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" fill="dodgerblue"> Click me </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I did a small fix: `<svg viewBox="0 0 110 110">` https://jsfiddle.net/0bkqpryL/

Comment: @JudahA Did you like the animation?

Comment: It's funny, but meanwhile I don't need it.

Comment: I also did a little adjesting for the path: `d="M 8.5,55 A 46.5,46.5 0 0 1 101.5,55"` https://jsfiddle.net/0bkqpryL/1/
Thank you Alexandr! You opened me the door for SVG!

Comment: @JudahA You can read more of my other answers. See my profile. I try to explain in detail. Maybe this will help you more.